# Como escrever uma lista encadeada simples em C++ sem usar <list>?

Tags: c++

Estou usando o operador `delete` para liberar um bloco de memoria  alocado via `new`, porém, ao executar o código pelo terminal ele parece não executar. Nenhum erro de código, simplesmente não executa no terminal. Se eu comentar a linha de código em que eu uso o `delete`, ai sim o código é executado normalmente no terminal. Tentei executar o mesmo código no IDE Dev-C++ e nele funciona normal. Alguém saberia me diz porque isso acontece? E como consertar?
o `Delete` está comentado da função `RemovePosicao()` na linha 157, ao executar com ele comentado então é executado no terminal, se tirar o comentário, então, acontece o que já foi mencionado anteriormente.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    /*
    1 - instanciar lista
    2 - inserir início
    3 - inserir fim
    4 - inserir por posição
    5 - imprimir
    5.5 - tamanho
    6 - remover inicio
    7 - remover fim
    8 - remover posição
    */

// delete apontador
void ExibirMenu()
{
    cout << "\n[1] - Inserir no inicio da lista\n";
    cout << "[2] - Inserir no fim da lista\n";
    cout << "[3] - Inserir por posicao\n";
    cout << "[4] - Imprimir lista\n";
    cout << "[5] - Remover no inicio da lista\n";
    cout << "[6] - Remover no fim da lista\n";
    cout << "[7] - Remover por posicao\n";
}

struct noLista
{
    int      dado;
    noLista *prox;
};

noLista *inicializar() { return NULL; }

void inserirInicio(noLista *&l, int info)
{
    noLista *novo = new noLista;
    novo->dado    = info;
    novo->prox    = l;
    l             = novo;
}

bool RemoveInicio(noLista *&ApontadorInicioLista)
{
    if (ApontadorInicioLista != NULL)
    {
        noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoExcluir = ApontadorInicioLista;
        ApontadorInicioLista = ApontadorInicioLista->prox;
        // delete (PonteiroPegaPosicaoExcluir);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void inserirFim(noLista *&l, int info)
{
    noLista *novo = new noLista;
    novo->dado    = info;
    novo->prox    = NULL;
    if (l == NULL) { l = novo; }
    else
    {
        noLista *p = l;
        while (p->prox != NULL) { p = p->prox; }
        p->prox = novo;
    }
}

bool RemoveFim(noLista *&ApontadorInicioLista)
{
    noLista *PonteiroPercorre = ApontadorInicioLista;
    noLista *PonteiroGuardaPosicaoAnterior;
    if (ApontadorInicioLista == NULL) { return false; }
    else if (ApontadorInicioLista->prox == NULL)
    {
        ApontadorInicioLista = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        while (PonteiroPercorre->prox != NULL)
        {
            PonteiroGuardaPosicaoAnterior = PonteiroPercorre;
            PonteiroPercorre              = PonteiroPercorre->prox;
        }
        PonteiroGuardaPosicaoAnterior->prox = NULL;
        return true;
    }
}

void imprimir(noLista *l)
{
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        cout << l->dado << "\n";
        l = l->prox;
    }
}

int tamanho(noLista *l)
{
    int cont = 0;
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        cont++;
        l = l->prox;
    }
    return cont;
}

bool inserir_posicao(noLista *&l, int info, int pos)
{
    int tam = tamanho(l);
    if (pos > tam + 1) { return false; }
    else if (pos <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pos == 1) { inserirInicio(l, info); }
        else if (pos == tam + 1)
        {
            inserirFim(l, info);
        }
        else
        {
            int      cont = 1;
            noLista *novo = new noLista;
            novo->dado    = info;
            // novo->prox
            noLista *p = l;
            while (cont < pos - 1)
            {
                p = p->prox;
                cont++;
            }
            novo->prox = p->prox;
            p->prox    = novo;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool RemovePosicao(noLista *&ApontadorInicioLista, int Posicao)
{
    int Tamanho = tamanho(ApontadorInicioLista);
    if (Posicao > Tamanho) { return false; }
    else if (Posicao <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Posicao == 1) { RemoveInicio(ApontadorInicioLista); }
        else
        {
            int      Contador = 1;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete = ApontadorInicioLista;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro;
            while (Contador != Posicao)
            {
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior = PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete;
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete =
                    PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete->prox;
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro =
                    PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete->prox;
                Contador++;
            }
            PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior->prox =
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro;
            // delete PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    noLista *l1 = inicializar();
    int      Terminar, opcao, valor, posicao;
    do {
        ExibirMenu();
        cout << "\nDigite uma opcao : ";
        cin >> opcao;
        switch (opcao)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                inserirInicio(l1, valor);
                cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                inserirFim(l1, valor);
                cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                cout << "\nEm qual posicao ? ";
                cin >> posicao;
                if (inserir_posicao(l1, valor, posicao))
                {
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nPosicao invalida ! \n";
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "\nAbaixo estao os elementos da lista \n\n";
                imprimir(l1);
                break;
            case 5:
                if (RemoveInicio(l1))
                {
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nLista vazia, impossivel realizar "
                            "operacao ! \n";
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (RemoveFim(l1))
                {
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nLista vazia, impossivel realizar "
                            "operacao ! \n";
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << "\nQual a posicao que voce deseja excluir ? ";
                cin >> posicao;
                if (RemovePosicao(l1, posicao))
                {
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nPosicao invalida ! \n";
                }
        }

        cout << "\n\
Deseja encerrar as operacoes com a lista ? Digite [0] para encerrar : ";
        cin >> Terminar;

    } while (Terminar != 0);
}
```

Comment: Isso é undefined behaviour. Você provavelmente está acessando o bloco de memória depois de usar o delete. Mas como você não colocou o código, difícil ter certeza.

Comment: poste o código... E considere que programas rodando dentro do IDE bem como programas compilados em debug mode, são coisas diferentes que o programa compilado e rodando no terminal.

Comment: Bom, postei o código, já que pensava que o problema era com as configurações do VS Code !

Comment: Bom nesse mesmo código eu consegui resolver o problema, apenas colocando o Colchetes depois do delete e antes do ponteiro. Queria saber o porque nesse caso ser preciso o colchetes!     `delete [] PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete;`

Comment: Não precisa dos colchetes

Answer (score -2):

O código como escreveu tem alguns problemas. Mas na máquina Windows 10 que estou usando funcionou em `gcc` e `MSVC` apesar dos avisos de variável não inicializada do compilador da Microsoft.

- Em `RemoveFim()` não há um `delete` para o nó.
- Se tem `void inserirInicio()` e `void inserirInicio()` então ao invés de `bool inserir_posicao()` devia ter `bool inserirPosicao()`. E se as 3 retornarem `bool` o código fica mais simples.
- nomes incrivelmente longos, como em

```
  bool RemovePosicao(noLista *&ApontadorInicioLista, int Posicao)
{
    int Tamanho = tamanho(ApontadorInicioLista);
    if (Posicao > Tamanho) { return false; }
    else if (Posicao <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Posicao == 1) { RemoveInicio(ApontadorInicioLista); }
        else
        {
            int      Contador = 1;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete = ApontadorInicioLista;
            noLista *PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro;
            while (Contador != Posicao)
            {
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior = PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete;
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete =
                    PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete->prox;
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro =
                    PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete->prox;
                Contador++;
            }
            PonteiroPegaPosicaoAnterior->prox =
                PonteiroPegaPosicaoPosteriro;
            // delete PonteiroPegaPosicaoDelete;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

não ajudam em nada a ler o código.

Veja essa opção, que também funciona:

```
bool noLista::RemovePosicao(int Posicao)
{
    if (Posicao > tamanho) return false;
    if (Posicao < 1) return false;
    if (Posicao == 1) return RemoveInicio();
    int   Contador = 1;
    Node* ant      = nullptr;
    Node* p        = inicio;
    Node* prox     = nullptr;
    while (Contador != Posicao)
    {
        ant  = p;
        p    = p->prox;
        prox = p->prox;
        Contador++;
    };  // while()
    ant->prox = prox;
    delete p;
    tamanho -= 1;
    return true;
}
```

- Não há razão para usar essas funções assim em C++ e passar em todas uma referência ao ponteiro para o início da lista. As funções fazem parte da classe (`struct` no seu caso). Apenas declare lá e tudo fica mais simples.
- entenda que uma lista não é um nó e um nó não é uma lista. Não programe assim. Uma lista é um conjunto, possivelmente vazio, de nós. E cada nó tem ou indica um dado, o elemento da lista. No seu caso é apenas um `int`. E em geral dentro do elemento tem um campo que é chamado **chave**, porque na lista está em geral implícita uma questão de ordem, uma noção de comparação. Em termos simples deve estar definido o operador `<` para a classe de coisas que tem dentro da lista.
- `main()` deve ser a primeira função de seu programa, se possível em um arquivo separado.
- um `cout` de 7 linhas é bem melhor que 7 `cout` de uma linha

**Você escreveu:**

```
void ExibirMenu()
{
    cout << "\n[1] - Inserir no inicio da lista\n";
    cout << "[2] - Inserir no fim da lista\n";
    cout << "[3] - Inserir por posicao\n";
    cout << "[4] - Imprimir lista\n";
    cout << "[5] - Remover no inicio da lista\n";
    cout << "[6] - Remover no fim da lista\n";
    cout << "[7] - Remover por posicao\n";
}
```

```
Mas void ExibirMenu() podia ser simplesmente int menu() e retornar a opção.
```

**Compare com:**

```
char menu()
{
    char opcao[30]{0};
    do {
        cout << "\
\n\
[0] - Sair\n\
[1] - Inserir no inicio da lista\n\
[2] - Inserir no fim da lista\n\
[3] - Inserir por posicao\n\
[4] - Imprimir lista\n\
[5] - Remover no inicio da lista\n\
[6] - Remover no fim da lista\n\
[7] - Remover por posicao\n\
\n\
      Digite uma opcao (0 para sair): ";
        cin.getline(opcao, 30);

    } while ((opcao[0] < '0') || (opcao[0] > '7'));

    return (opcao[0] - '0');
}
```

Que tem a vantagem de ler a linha toda. E é possivelmente mais fácil de ler e de alterar. E em `main()` já pode usar o valor diretamente como em

```
    while(true)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
        }
    }
```

E em uma única chamada a `cout`.

Considere essas definições:

```
// noLista.h
struct Node
{
    int   dado;
    Node* prox;
};

struct noLista
{
    Node*   Inicio();
    void    Imprimir();
    bool    InserirFim(int info);
    bool    InserirInicio(int info);
    bool    InserirPosicao(int info, int pos);
    bool    RemoveFim();
    bool    RemoveInicio();
    bool    RemovePosicao(int Posicao);
    int     Tamanho();

    noLista();  // inicializar
    ~noLista(); // apaga tudo

   private:
    Node* inicio;
    int   tamanho;
};
// fim de noLista.h
```

Isso seria um modo mais simples de escrever o que fez, em C++. Assim as funções da lista ficam associadas a uma lista. Em geral se escreve que os métodos de `noLista` ficam associados a *instâncias* da classe.

E o `tamanho` faz parte da lista, dentro da struct, assim não precisa percorrer a lista a cada vez que precisa do tamanho dela. E pode usar esse valor para controlar outras funções.

Exemplo:

```
    noLista l1; // l1 e uma lista
    l1.imprimir(); // se refere a lista l1.
    
    noLista minhalista[10]; // 10 listas ligadas
    minha_lista[4],imprimir(); // imprime o conteudo da 5a lista
```

#### Um exemplo em C++ de uma lista encadeada simples

Vou deixar um exemplo (com seu código) a seguir.

- Entenda que, a menos que seja obrigado por um enunciado ou um projeto ou uma máquina sem recursos, não deve usar ponteiros para um lado só: é mais complicado e não mais simples. Sem ponteiros para os dois lados toda vez que precisar navegar pela lista pode precisar se reposicionar no início (ou no fim) e começar de novo. Ou salvar o ponteiro faltante na função de novo e de novo e novo... Veja no exemplo abaixo as funções que removem ou inserem no fim.
- evite misturar entrada e saída com as funções da lista. Use estruturas genéricas e sempre vai poder usar as mesmas funções
- C++ tem listas em `<list>`. Sempre é por ver os [métodos oferecidos](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/),
- Em geral funções que inserem ou removem por posição não são assim úteis em listas e pilhas, e uma função que lista todos só existe para teste. `list` é um *container* voltado à navegação simples e inserção rápida. E em geral se insere e remove por uma ordem determinada pelo operador `<` que deve existir para a classe contéudo da lista.
- veja no exemplo como codificar as funções que manipulam a lista: elas ficam DENTRO da estrutura e por isso não precisa passar um ponteiro para a lista. Isto é encapsulamento e é em geral muito mais conveniente.

#### O código do exemplo

Há muitas razões para escrever assim, mas programas em C++ costumam ter um arquivo de código e um arquivo de cabeçalho para cada classe.

Nesse caso aqui tem a classe `Node`, que aqui é uma `struct`, e a classe `noLista` que é também uma `struct`.

Assim nesse exemplo o normal é ter 3 arquivos: noLista.h com as declarações, noLista.cpp com a implementação das funções, e o arquivo .cpp que chama as funções.

Assim você pode escrever vários programas que usam `noLista.cpp`. Ou pode escrever várias implementações de teste para a `struct` definida em `noLista.h`

#### noLista.h

```
// noLista.h
struct Node
{
    int   dado;
    Node* prox;
};

struct noLista
{
    Node*   Inicio();
    void    Imprimir();
    bool    InserirFim(int info);
    bool    InserirInicio(int info);
    bool    InserirPosicao(int info, int pos);
    bool    RemoveFim();
    bool    RemoveInicio();
    bool    RemovePosicao(int Posicao);
    int     Tamanho();

    noLista();  // inicializar
    ~noLista(); // apaga tudo

   private:
    Node* inicio;
    int   tamanho;
};
// fim de noLista.h
```

#### uma implementação de `NoLista.h`

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "noLista.h"
using namespace std;

// constroi uma lista vazia
noLista::noLista()
{
    inicio  = nullptr;
    tamanho = 0;
};  // inicializar

// apaga a lista
noLista::~noLista()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1) RemoveInicio();
};

// os metodos 

Node* noLista::Inicio() { return inicio; }

void noLista::Imprimir()
{
    int   nc = 0;
    cout << "Total de " << tamanho << " elementos:\n\n";
    Node* p = inicio;
    for ( int i = 0; i<tamanho; i+=1, p=p->prox)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << p->dado << " ";
        if (++nc % 10 == 0) cout << "\n";  // 10 por linha
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

bool noLista::InserirInicio(int info)
{
    Node* novo = new Node;
    novo->dado = info;
    novo->prox = inicio;
    inicio     = novo;
    tamanho += 1;
    return true;
}

bool noLista::InserirFim(int info)
{
    Node* novo = new Node;
    novo->dado = info;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    if (tamanho == 0) return InserirInicio(info);
    Node* p = inicio;
    while (p->prox != NULL) { p = p->prox; }
    p->prox = novo;
    tamanho += 1;
    return true;
}

bool noLista::InserirPosicao(int info, int pos)
{
    if (pos > tamanho + 1) return false;
    if (pos <= 0) return false;
    if (pos == 1) return InserirInicio(info);
    if (pos == tamanho) return InserirFim(info);
    Node* novo = new Node;
    novo->dado = info;

    Node* p = inicio;
    // avanca pos - 1 nodes
    for (int cont = 1; cont < pos; cont += 1) p = p->prox;
    novo->prox = p->prox;
    p->prox    = novo;
    tamanho += 1;
    return true;
}

bool noLista::RemoveFim()
{
    if (tamanho == 0) return false;
    if (tamanho == 1) { return RemoveInicio(); }
    Node* ant = nullptr;
    Node* p = inicio;
    while (p->prox != NULL)
    {
        ant = p;
        p              = p->prox;
    }
    if (ant != nullptr)
        ant->prox = NULL;
    else
        inicio = nullptr;
    delete p;
    tamanho -= 1;
    return true;
}

bool noLista::RemoveInicio()
{
    if (tamanho == 0) return true;  // vazia
    Node* novo_inicio = inicio->prox;
    delete inicio;
    inicio = novo_inicio;
    tamanho -= 1;
    return true;
}

bool noLista::RemovePosicao(int Posicao)
{
    if (Posicao > tamanho) return false;
    if (Posicao < 1) return false;
    if (Posicao == 1) return RemoveInicio();
    int   Contador = 1;
    Node* ant      = nullptr;
    Node* p        = inicio;
    Node* prox     = nullptr;
    while (Contador != Posicao)
    {
        ant  = p;
        p    = p->prox;
        prox = p->prox;
        Contador++;
    };  // while()
    ant->prox = prox;
    delete p;
    tamanho -= 1;
    return true;
}

int noLista::Tamanho() { return tamanho; }
```

As funções tem em geral umas 10 linhas de código e não há muito que comentar. É praticamene seu código afinal.

#### `main()` com o meu original

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "noLista.h"
char        menu();

int main(void)
{
    noLista l1;
    int     posicao = 0;
    int     valor = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
            case 0:
                return 0; // fim
                break;

            case 1:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                l1.InserirInicio(valor);
                cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                l1.InserirFim(valor);
                cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "\nQual valor a ser inserido ? ";
                cin >> valor;
                cout << "\nEm qual posicao ? ";
                cin >> posicao;
                if ( l1.InserirPosicao(valor, posicao))
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                else
                    cout << "\nPosicao invalida ! \n";
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "\nAbaixo estao os elementos da lista \n\n";
                l1.Imprimir();
                break;

            case 5:
                if (l1.RemoveInicio())
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                else
                    cout << "\nLista vazia, impossivel realizar "
                            "operacao ! \n";
                break;

            case 6:
                if (l1.RemoveFim())
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                else
                    cout << "\nLista vazia, impossivel realizar "
                            "operacao ! \n";
                break;

            case 7:
                cout << "\nQual a posicao que voce deseja excluir ? ";
                cin >> posicao;
                if (l1.RemovePosicao(posicao))
                    cout << "\nOperacao realizada com sucesso ! \n";
                else
                    cout << "\nPosicao invalida ! \n";
        }
    };  // while()
    return 0; // para contentar o compilador
}

char menu()
{
    char opcao[30]{0};
    do
    {
        cout << "\
\n\
[0] - Sair\n\
[1] - Inserir no inicio da lista\n\
[2] - Inserir no fim da lista\n\
[3] - Inserir por posicao\n\
[4] - Imprimir lista\n\
[5] - Remover no inicio da lista\n\
[6] - Remover no fim da lista\n\
[7] - Remover por posicao\n\
\n\
      Digite uma opcao (0 para sair): ";
        cin.getline(opcao, 30);

    }   while ((opcao[0] < '0') || (opcao[0] > '7'));

    return (opcao[0] - '0');
}
```

E pode ver como parece mais simples.

Por outro lado, como os arquivos estão separados, pod eusar outros programas de teste sem mexer nonoLista.cpp...

#### um programa de teste para as funções

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "noLista.h"
int main(void)
{
    noLista l1;
    int     posicao = 0;
    int     valor   = 0;
    for ( int valor = 20; valor>=1; valor-=1 ) 
       l1.InserirPosicao(valor,1);
    l1.Imprimir();
    cout << "Tamanho agora: " << l1.Tamanho() << endl;
    while (1)
    {
        if (l1.RemovePosicao(1)) 
            cout << "RemoveFim() ok, restam " << l1.Tamanho() << "\n";
        else
        {
            cout << "RemoveFim() Erro restam " << l1.Tamanho() << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    l1.Imprimir();
    return 0;  // para contentar o compilador
}
```

Esse teste apenas insere 20 paras na primeira posição, mostra e depois remove o primeiro até dar erro, de modo que a lista ao final vai estar vazia...

Assim pode escrever pequenos programas e testar as funções sem mexer no código da lista...

#### Saída desse teste

```
Total de 20 elementos:

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20

Tamanho agora: 20
RemoveFim() ok, restam 19
RemoveFim() ok, restam 18
RemoveFim() ok, restam 17
RemoveFim() ok, restam 16
RemoveFim() ok, restam 15
RemoveFim() ok, restam 14
RemoveFim() ok, restam 13
RemoveFim() ok, restam 12
RemoveFim() ok, restam 11
RemoveFim() ok, restam 10
RemoveFim() ok, restam 9
RemoveFim() ok, restam 8
RemoveFim() ok, restam 7
RemoveFim() ok, restam 6
RemoveFim() ok, restam 5
RemoveFim() ok, restam 4
RemoveFim() ok, restam 3
RemoveFim() ok, restam 2
RemoveFim() ok, restam 1
RemoveFim() ok, restam 0
RemoveFim() Erro restam 0
Total de 0 elementos:
```